# Break out of foreach loop and continue again?

Tags: php, magento2

I have a foreach loop that runs through attributes of products and builds drop down boxes that the user can choose from. I want to break that loop as soon as a attribute named delivery shows up. With that attribute I want to build my own drop down box (change the number values into dates) but then I want it to continue building the rest of the products drop down boxes.... Is it possible? I have tried else, elseif, endif and whatever I can think of but I just cant do it.

The Loop:

```
<?php foreach ($_attributes as $_attribute): ?>

    My delivery attribute values
   <?php $_deliveryDate = $_product->getAttributeText('deliverydate'); 

   <div class="control">
   <select name="super_attribute[<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_attribute->getAttributeId() ?>]"
   data-selector="super_attribute[<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_attribute->getAttributeId() ?>]"
   data-validate="{required:true}"
   id="attribute<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_attribute->getAttributeId() ?>"
   class="super-attribute-select">
   <option value=""><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Choose an Option...') ?></option>
   </select>
```

Can I somehow breakout of this loop or update the numbers (4, 7, 10) to dates before they populate tha drop down menus?

Comment: when you say "break out of the loop" you could also say "do something else besides" - which is basicly calling an external function (where you build your dropdown) from inside the loop

Comment: Do u have some kind of example? Thank u, Im gonna research it!

Comment: something like `$dropdown = createDropdown($_attribute); //maybe echo $dropdown;` - create a function called `createDropdown()` that does what you need...